# "Unfortunely, [Application] has stopped running" Volume 1238 (including Logcat)

Tags: android

The Application on my Android VM stops when creating an object. There are multiple questions regarding this error, but none of it has been helpful for me and its getting desperate now.

Logcat (filtered for "exception"):

```
06-29 06:35:19.189: W/dalvikvm(1035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
06-29 06:35:19.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 06:35:19.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.annoworkspace/com.example.annoworkspace.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
06-29 06:35:19.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
```

I create the object in MainActivity (when commented out, the application doesnt stop):

```
    parserClass parse = new parserClass(getApplicationContext());
```

If you are interested in the code of the parserClass, it's a bit long and muddy, but maybe it helps for error detection:

```
package com.example.annoworkspace;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class parserClass 
{

public ArrayList<String> content= new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap collection = new HashMap();

Cost cost = new Cost(0,0,0,0);
Production production = new Production("",0);
MaintenanceCost maintenanceCost = new MaintenanceCost(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Building building = new Building("", cost, production, maintenanceCost);

public TextView Anzeige1;

public InputStream in_s;


        public parserClass(Context context)
        {
            Log.d("Start parserClass", null, null);
            //Öffnen der XML
            try
            {
                InputStream in_s = context.getAssets().open("Buildings.xml");
            }
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   

            try 
            {
                xmlparser();
            } 
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



public void xmlparser() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException 
{

    String xmlInfo = "xml_parser";
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    xpp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);

    xpp.setInput(in_s, null);
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
            Log.d(xmlInfo, "Start document");
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            Log.d(xmlInfo, "End document");
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            Log.d(xmlInfo, "Start tag " + xpp.getName());

            //building tempBuilding;

            if (xpp.getName()=="Building")
            {
                //obsolete
            }
            else if(xpp.getName()=="Name")
            {
                building.name=xpp.nextText();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Cost")
            {
                //
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Credits")
            {
                cost.credits = xpp.next();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Buildingmodules")
            {
                cost.buildingmodules = xpp.next();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Tools")
            {
                cost.tools = xpp.next();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Concrete")
            {
                cost.concrete = xpp.next();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Production")
            {}
            else if (xpp.getName() == "Product")
                production.product = xpp.nextText();
            else if (xpp.getName() == "ProductionSpeed")
            {
                production.productionSpeed = xpp.next();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName() == "MaintenanceCost")
            {
                //
            }
            else if (xpp.getName()== "ActiveCost")
            {
                maintenanceCost.activeCost = xpp.next();
            }
            else if (xpp.getName()== "InactiveCost")
            {
                maintenanceCost.inactiveCost = xpp.next();
            }

            else if (xpp.getName()== "ActiveEcoEffect")
            {
                maintenanceCost.activeEcoEffect = xpp.next();
            }

            else if (xpp.getName()== "InactiveEcoEffect")
            {
                maintenanceCost.inactiveEcoEffect = xpp.next();
            }

            else if (xpp.getName()== "ActiveEnergyCost")
            {
                maintenanceCost.activeEnergyCost = xpp.next();
            }

            else if (xpp.getName()== "InactiveEnergyCost")
            {
                maintenanceCost.inactiveEnergyCost = xpp.next();
            }




        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
            Log.d(xmlInfo, "End tag " + xpp.getName());
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            if (xpp.getText().length() == 4) 
            {
                Log.d(xmlInfo, xpp.getText());

            }
            else 
            {
                Log.d(xmlInfo, xpp.getText());
                //serverName = xpp.getText();
            }
        }

        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
}







}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local variable `in_s` shadows your member variable `in_s`, and thus the member variable is unassigned (`null`).

This is probably just a typo on your part.

Comment: This was actually the reason the application stopped. I fixed it, and now it works.